# Next js Redirect to other domains Not Working

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing, nextjs-rewrites

I can redirect to the path in same domain but enable to redirect if domain is different. This error only occurs on firebase hosting and is working fine on localhost with `yarn dev`.

code:

```
const router = useRouter();
router.push("https://www.example.com/auth") //doesnot work
router.push("/dashboard"); //works
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "out",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "/",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    },
{
    "source": "/dashboard",
    "destination": "/dashboard.html"
  }
   ]
  }
}
```

I am looking into firebase json file as I believe problem is there.